# Using Sortable on Dynamically Created UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-lists, jquery-ui-sortable

This is probably an easy question for someone who uses JQuery regularly. I am simply reading a list from S3 into an array and using

```
document.getElementById('my-list').appendChild(makeUL(options));
```

to build a ul inside of a div with an id of my-list. It looks something like this:

```
<div id="my-list">
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">LivePD</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Football</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Walking Dead</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Survivor</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">The Voice</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Shark Tank</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">DWTS</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">RHOOC</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have the sortable function as:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable();
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });
</script>
```

Here's the problem. If I hard code the ul into my HTML body as it is show above, the sortable code runs fine. It adds the ui-sortable class to the ul and li elements as it is supposed to. If I build the ul dynamically using getElementById, the base HTML renders exactly the same, but sortable does not add the classes.

Does this have something to do with the order in which the DOM is executing? I simply can't figure it out and can not find another example of this anywhere. Completely open to other ideas as well.

Comment: everytime after  building the ul dynamically call these `$("#sortable").sortable();
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();` also.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Just added a call to the sortable function immediately after the ul was built in the DOM. I assumed it had something to do with order of execution. I haven't done much web/js dev and just figuring it out as I go along. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review:

[jQuery UI API Sortable Refresh Method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh)

It says:

> Refresh the sortable items. Triggers the reloading of all sortable items, causing new items to be recognized.

When adding elements dynamically, you will either add them before initializing  Sortable or after. If done before, you just assemble the list items and then call sortable. If after, add the items and then run the refresh method.

Here is a somewhat complex example, but it assumes you're adding items from an API based list and maybe adding more items later.

```js
$(function() {
  var extData = [{
    label: "LivePD",
    id: 1
  }, {
    label: "Football",
    id: 2
  }, {
    label: "Walking Dead",
    id: 3
  }, {
    label: "Survivor",
    id: 4
  }, {
    label: "The Voice",
    id: 5
  }, {
    label: "Shark Tank",
    id: 6
  }, {
    label: "DWTS",
    id: 7
  }, {
    label: "RHOOC",
    id: 8
  }];

  function updateList(data, target) {
    var sort = target.find(".sortable");
    console.log(data, sort);
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      $("<li>", {
        class: "ui-state-default",
        id: target.attr("id") + "-item-" + v.id
      }).html(v.label).appendTo(sort);
    });
    if (sort.hasClass("ui-sortable")) {
      sort.sortable("refresh");
    }
  }

  updateList(extData, $("#my-list"));
  $(".sortable").sortable();
  $(".sortable").disableSelection();
  $(".add").click(function(e) {
    var dlg = $("<div>", {
      title: "Add To " + $(this).parent().find("p").text()
    });
    var that = $(this);
    dlg.append(
      $("<label>").html("Name"),
      $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "name txt"
      }),
      $("<label>").html("ID"),
      $("<input>", {
        type: "input",
        class: "id txt"
      })
    );
    dlg.dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: [{
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() {
          var d = [{
            label: $(this).find(".name").val(),
            id: $(this).find(".id").val()
          }];
          updateList(d, that.parent());
          $(this).dialog("close");
          $(this).remove();
        }
      }, {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          $(this).remove();
        }
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

.sortable li {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

.sortable li span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}

.ui-dialog-content label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="my-list">
  <p>My List</p>
  <ul class="sortable">
  </ul>
  <button id="my-list-add-btn" class="add btn">Add</button>
</div>
```

If you have more than 1 list, this code works very well, as it allows you to use the same function for many different lists.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great example. Will need this as I grow this experiment for updating as new items are rendered. Appreciate the input.

Comment: @SGraham if you found this answer or others helpful, remember to upvote them. Also remember to mark one of them as the answer.

Comment: Done. I guess I'm so new to SO that I can't officially upvote until my rep improves 

Comment: @SGraham it will improve. Marking a response as the answer helps with that.

Answer (score -1):

Ya just call

```
$("#sortable").sortable(); $("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

every time after dynamic fill.

Happy coding.

Comment: I downvoted this answer as OP already has these elements in their code. Also this is not the proper way to refresh a sortable list when adding new items. Please see: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: I think the spirit of the answer, based on the question, was fine. My original problem was fairly elementary given that I was simply testing the concept. The problem, in that context, was that I was simply calling the sortable function in the wrong order of DOM execution - rookie with web dev. Thanks all for your help and input. The comprehensive answer from Twisty is certainly the right implementation going forward.